# tried everything-type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I know this questions has been asked a lot and I read pretty much all of the answers. I even checked .NET versions and they are same. I wrote a Rectangle class in project called Problem1 (namesapce Problem1) and wanted to use it in another project Problem2. I added using Problem1 and it immediately got red saying:

```
"type or namespace name could not be found"
```

Now I compared mine solution to a working one, which is written exactly the same, yet mine is not working.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you add Problem1 as reference to Problem2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a reference to the project Problem1 in project Problem2

In solution Explorer:

1- right click on Project Problem2 and click on add reference

2- In the dialog that appears in the left pane click on Solution

3- In projects that appear after clicking the solution, select the project Problem1

4- click ok

Comment: it worked, thanks. One more question if you have time. when I go on to make object of class recangle i get an error: rectangle is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You have to declare the rectangle class either as public or internal